# Algorithm for finding the largest sum of squares

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Say I'm given a bunch of number pairs, is there a good algorithm to find the pair with the largest sum of their squares besides computing all sums of squares and comparing it to the current max?

eg
input:

```
[3, 3]
[0, 3]
[4, 0]
[2, 4]
```

output:
`[2, 4]` (sum of squares: 20)

Comment: You need at least to parse all the pairs isn't it? So this can't be shorter than "brute force" testing every pair. Sorting is a bad idea, because it would cost more than just parsing the list.

Comment: As mentioned, you need to parse the entire list once. However, if your list is large, then creating a new list of "SumSquare" values is not necessary [this will also cost memory]. You can use a generator to lazily evaluate the maximum. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: My focus is not on parsing. I wanted to know if I have to brutally compute all sums of squares and compare it to current max?  Or is it possible to avoid computing all these squares?

Comment: Iterating through a long list can be as costly as the computation. You need to perform *some* computation to find the max. If you are saying, can you reduce the 3 computations (`x*x`, `y*y`, `sum`) to less than 3, I can't see any way.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I could somehow apply binary search or some other methods to solve this problem. Couldn't figure out a way myself. Maybe there is none.

Comment: Not sure about this (just a quick idea) but maybe you can try the following to minimize the number of operations:

for each pair calculate (x+y+|x-y|) as some kind of score.
The biggest score is the max.
In case you have multiple same max scores, the biggest is the one with the min |x-y|.

Comment: You could eliminate duplicates, including pairs, like (a,b) and (b,a), but searching them is probably more costly than just computing the sum of squares. Similarly, for (a,b); (c,d) if c<a and d<b you wouldn't need to compute the sum, but here again, the test and preparation might be more costly than what you gain and lead to less readable code. If the costs of squaring were very high, I would flip the rows, where in (a,b) b>a to (b,a), sort by the first descending, so that for (a,b),(a,c) I would only look for (a,b). But sorting is probably too expensive.

Comment: However, it depends on how the data is distributed, too. If the likelihood is high for repeated values and pairs, other strategies look promising, than for a large value base with even distributed values.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. And to @IvanM, I was thinking about that too, however it doesn't seem to work. (8, 8) would get a score of 16, and (10, 5) would get 20, however the sum of squares of (8, 8) is greater than that of (10, 5).

Answer (score 0):

To use a binary search, you would need to sort the list.  This raises two problems (mentioned or hinted above):

- You don't have a well-ordered collection
- The optimal sort is **O(n log n)**

Sum of two squares is simple: two data accesses for the numbers, two multiplications, and an addition.  On a linear CPU, this pipelines to 3 cheap (i.e. single-cycle) operations.  On a modern AI processor, this is a single-cycle dot-product.

In short, not only is the linear, brute-force approach only **O(n)**, it's a *fast* **O(n)**.  Take the money and run.